# Is the Syntax of C Language completely defined by CFGs?

Tags: c, programming-languages, context-free-grammar, compiler-construction

I think the Question is self sufficient. Is the syntax of C Language completely defined through Context Free Grammars or do we have Language Constructs which may require non-Context Free definitions in the course of parsing?

An example of non CFL construct i thought was the declaration of variables before their use. But in Compilers(Aho Ullman Sethi), it is stated that the C Language does not distinguish between identifiers on the basis of their names. All the identifiers are tokenized as 'id' by the Lexical Analyzer.
If C is not completely defined by CFGs, please can anyone give an example of Non CFL construct in C?

Comment: Are we talking about the layman's interpretation of "context free" or about the precise CS definition of a context free grammar?

Comment: This question would be better asked on [cs.se]

Comment: precise definition of CFG.

Comment: id is always an identifier in c. this way a is also an id. And 'id=*a' is always an assignment expression.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Your example appears to be missing something -- perhaps context ;-) -- as it's not valid C code on its own regardless of what `id` refers to.

Comment: @delnan: correct never seen a c declaration like char=*p;

Comment: Sorry, my example was wrong. What I meant to write was "a * b;". If "a' is a variable it is an expression, if "a" is a typename  is a declaration.

Comment: @CharlieBurns That, however, is in principle a valid C program regardless of whether `a` is a variable or a type.

Comment: no @CharlieBurns & delnan a*b; is not an expression(unless you use it in an assignment statement which would give error if a is a type). in function call you may have something like foo(a*b); but argument matching is done in a recursive manner in c.

Comment: @Madeyedexter, I think you are wrong. a * b; by itself is just an expression statement. Doesn't need to be part of an assignment.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: apologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of Non Context free language in C language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012940/examples-of-non-context-free-language-in-c-language)

Comment: All I was trying to express, perhaps poorly, was that "a * b;" is the only C statement I can think of where I can't figure out what kind of a statement it is just by looking at it. That's why most C lexers have a token for ID and different token for TYPENAME. There are probably more, like "A(x)" as pointed out below.

Comment: @CharlieBurns, it's important to know that a CFG can be parsed by a CS parser, but that doesn't make the grammar CS. It may be easier for gcc for example to differentiate between ID and TYPENAME, but that's not specified in the C grammar, nor do you need to differentiate between the two to _parse_ the C program. To _understand_ the C program is another story.

Comment: @shahbaz: Parse `(foo)*x`, then. Is it a cast or a multiplication? If it doesn't matter, how are you defining "to parse".

Comment: @Madeyedexter: Can you be more precise about the quote from Aho, Sethi & Ullman? I can't find it in my copy, and it is certainly not true so it surprises me that you found such a statement.

Comment: In Chapter 4, Non Context Free Language constructs Section, there are 2 examples, one concerning declaration of variables before use, and the other concerning matching of number of actual to formal parameters.

Comment: @Madeyedexter: In my battered old 1986 copy, that sentence uses "Algol and Pascal" as examples, instead of "Java and C". However, the text clearly states "demonstrates the non-context-freedom of programming languages like [example languages], which require declaration of identifiers before their use". The next paragraph points out that real-life parsers use another mechanism to deal with this context-sensitivity. Even so, I think it's not true of C, because of `typedef`. None of Java, Algol nor Pascal have typedef, and that makes C different.

Comment: Read [Can someone give a simple but non-toy example of a context-sensitive grammar?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7716/can-someone-give-a-simple-but-non-toy-example-of-a-context-sensitive-grammar/7717#7717)

Comment: Understand: As a formal language C-language is (or set of all valid C programs are) CSL, C constructs like "declare fist then use variable makes C-language a CSL". But Unfortunately we don't know any efficient parsing technique to parse CSL, And hence be make use of CFL (and CFG) to parse syntax of C. And CSL constructs we have to explicitly handle by keeping information stored in some data-structures (for example we add semantic analysis phases).

Comment: `it is stated that the C Language does not distinguish between identifiers on the basis of their names. All the identifiers are tokenized as 'id' by the Lexical Analyzer`. Yes during the lexical analysis identifies stores in Symbol table with assigned id. During Syntax and Semantic analysis Information about identifies also updated in table.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you haven't defined "the syntax of C".

If you define it as the language C in the CS sense, meaning the set of all valid C programs, then C – as well as virtually every other language aside from turing tarpits and Lisp – is not context free. The reasons are **not** related to the problem of *interpreting* a C program (e.g. deciding whether `a * b;` is a multiplication or a declaration). Instead, it's simply because context free grammars can't help you decide whether a given string is a valid C program. Even something as simple as `int main() { return 0; }` needs a more powerful mechanism than context free grammars, as you have to (1) remember the return type and (2) check that whatever occurs after the `return` matches the return type. `a * b;` faces a similar problem – you don't need to know whether it's a multiplication, but if it is a multiplication, that must be a valid operation for the types of `a` and `b`. I'm not actually sure whether a context *sensitive* grammar is enough for all of C, as some restrictions on valid C programs are quite subtle, even if you exclude undefined behaviour (some of which may even be undecidable).

Of course, the above notion is hardly useful. Generally, when talking grammars, we're only interested in a pretty good approximation of a valid program: We want a grammar that rules out as many strings which aren't C as possible without undue complexity in the grammar (for example, `1 a` or `(-)`). Everything else is left to later phases of the compiler and called a semantic error or something similar to distinguish it from the first class of errors. *These* "approximate" grammars are almost always context free grammars (including in C's case), so if you want to call this approximation of the set of valid programs "syntax", C is indeed defined by a context free grammar. Many people do, so you'd be in good company.

Comment: _as you have to (1) remember the return type and (2) check that whatever occurs after the return matches the return type._ this is semantics, not syntax.

Comment: Also, the whole C compiler _is_ context sensitive as it can be expressed by a linear bounded automata (Basically your memory requirements is linear to the number of tokens in the translation unit)

Comment: @Shahbaz The whole point of my answer is it depends on what you mean by syntax and semantics. If by "syntactically valid" you mean "is a valid C program according to the full specification", you do need to know that, because validity includes type checking. Of course, by the common (vague but useful) definition of syntax and semantics you're right, but that's precisely what I'm talking about in the *second* part of my answer.

Comment: @Shahbaz Good point about linear bounded automata. (It's good that you said tokens, because preprocessing might cause exponential blowup.)

Comment: where ever I had heard before parsing and syntax are tied concepts. Parsing relates to matching the stream of tokens coming from the lexer to a grammar which is called syntax. Semantics is what comes after.

Comment: Yeah preprocessing is a whole other thing. I haven't thought about if the grammar of the preprocessor is CF or not, though.

Comment: @Shahbaz And which errors are caught by the parser and which are caught by the parts concerned with "semantics" is the "precision of the grammar" I was talking about ;-) If you're too careless with these simplifications, you can claim balanced parentheses are a regular language - just parse with the regex `[\(\)]*` and any imbalance is a semantic error. But I admit, my insistence on this point is partially to justify my rambling about formal languages. As for preprocessing, I think it's context free as any tokens it can't make sense of (like `undefined_macro(x)`) are valid and just left alone.

Comment: On the same line as to why I associate parsing and syntax, one example is the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) which is generated at parse time. Regarding your comment, I'd have to think about it (and have to go home now also ;)). But the fact that unknown tokens are not reported doesn't necessarily mean that it's context free (even though it probably really is context free, but for a more ... _formal_ ... reason.

Comment: `I'm not actually sure whether a context sensitive grammar is enough for all of C`. Yes a CSG can represent set-of-all-valid-C-codes. But the thing is we don't know any efficient parsing technique for CSL. A good example is `int a = 10, b = a;`

Answer (score 2):

The `C` language, as defined by the language standard, includes the preprocessor. The following is a syntactically correct C program:

```
#define START int main(
#define MIDDLE ){

START int argc, char** argv MIDDLE return 0; }
```

It seems to be really tempting to answer this question (which arises a lot) "sure, there is a CFG for C", based on extracting a subset of the grammar in the standard, which grammar in itself is ambiguous and recognizes a superset of the language. That CFG is interesting and even useful, but *it is not C*.

In fact, the productions in the standard do not even attempt to describe what a syntactically correct source file is. They describe:

1. The lexical structure of the source file (along with the lexical structure of valid tokens after pre-processing).
2. The grammar of individual preprocessor directives
3. A superset of the grammar of the post-processed language, which relies on some other mechanism to distinguish between `typedef-name` and other uses of `identifier`, as well as a mechanism to distinguish between `constant-expression` and other uses of `conditional-expression`.

There are many who argue that the issues in point 3 are "semantic", rather than "syntactic". However, the nature of C (and even more so its cousin C++) is that it is impossible to disentangle "semantics" from the parsing of a program. For example, the following is a syntactically correct C program:

```
#define base 7
#if base * 2 < 10
  &one ?= two*}}
#endif

int main(void){ return 0; }
```

So if you really mean "is the syntax of the C language defined by a CFG", the answer must be no. If you meant, "Is there a CFG which defines the syntax of some language which represents strings which are an intermediate product of the translation of a program in the C language," it's possible that the answer is yes, although some would argue that the necessity to make precise what is a `constant-expression` and a `typedef-name` make the syntax necessarily context-sensitive, in a way that other languages are not.

Comment: Why would the parser _need_ to distinguish typedefed names and identifiers? There is no such distinction in the (CFG) grammar of C written on sections in the standard itself. Even if it did, it means the grammar is _ambiguous_, not context-sensitive.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Because parsing is not just recognizing. It's not enough to verify that the input is an element of (a superset of) the language; a parser must also generate some representation of the derivation, typically an AST. And you can't do that for C unless you know which symbols are `typedef-name`s (which, yes, is a production in the standard.)

Comment: typedef-name expands to id, so from the point of view of gramattical correctness, it doesn't matter if x in `x y;` is a typedef or not. Convenience or output fron a parser also doesn't determine context-free-ness of a language. Like I said, you seem to be confusing ambiguity with context-sensitive-ness.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the syntax of C Language completely defined through Context Free Grammars?

Yes it is. This is the grammar of C in BNF:

[http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Epjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf)

If you don't see other than exactly one symbol on the left hand side of any rule, then the grammar is context free. That is the very definition of [context free grammars (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar):

> In formal language theory, a context-free grammar (CFG) is a formal grammar in which every production rule is of the form
>
> ```
> V → w
> ```
>
> where V is a single nonterminal symbol, and w is a string of terminals and/or nonterminals (w can be empty).

---

Since ambiguity is mentioned by others, I would like to clarify a bit. Imagine the following grammar:

```
A -> B x | C x
B -> y
C -> y
```

This is an ambiguous grammar. However, it is still a context free grammar. These two are completely separate concepts.

---

Obviously, the semantics analyzer of C is context sensitive. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025320/912144) from the duplicate question has further explanations.

Comment: The grammar you link to is a CFG, but it does not completely define the syntax of C. E.g., it doesn't deal with preprocessing directives or most lexical matters (tokens, whitespace, comments, etc.).

Comment: @MichaelDyck, the grammar is based on terminals and non-terminals. Sure the lexer (including preprocessor) defines what is a terminal and what is not, but once determined (through another language), the result is accepted by a CFG.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here:

1. The structure of the language (syntax): this is context free as you do not need to know the surroundings to figure out what is an identifier and what is a function.
2. The meaning of the program (semantics): this is not context free as you need to know whether an identifier has been declared and with what type when you are referring to it.

Comment: I don't think #2 is a useful criteria, for two reasons: It's a mismatch with the formal CFG concept, which describes languages as sets of strings with no mention of semantics. (2) Virtually no language of interest is "context free" under this definition. I don't think you can even have a turing complete language that is "context free" according to #2, as CFGs aren't as powerful as turing machines.

Comment: @delnan - right, but it explains where confusion of the OP comes from

Comment: I don't think OP is *that* confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by the "syntax of C" all valid C strings that some C compiler accepts, and after running the pre-processor, but *ignoring typing errors*, then this is the answer: yes but not unambiguously.

First, you could assume the input program is tokenized according to the C standard. The grammar will describe relations among these tokens and not the bare characters. Such context-free grammars are found in books about C and in implementations that use parser generators. This tokenization is a big assumption because quite some work goes into "lexing" C. So, I would argue that we have not described C with a context-free grammar yet, if we have not used context-free grammars to describe the lexical level. The staging between the tokenizer and the parser combined with the ordering emposed by a scanner generator (prefer keywords, longest match, etc) are a major increase in computational power which is not easily simulated in a context-free grammar.

So, If you do not assume a tokenizer which for example can distinguish type names from variable names using a symbol table, then a context-free grammar is going to be harder. However: the trick here is to accept ambiguity. We can describe the syntax of C including its tokens in a context-free grammar fully. Only the grammar will be ambiguous and produce different interpretations for the same string . For example for `A *a;` it will have derivations for a multiplication and a pointer declaration both. No problem, the grammar is still describing the C syntax as you requested, just not unambiguously.

Notice that we have assumed having run the pre-processor first as well, I believe your question was not about the code as it looks before pre-processing. Describing that using a context-free grammar would be just madness since syntactic correctness depends on the semantics of expanding user-defined macros. Basically, the programmer is extending the syntax of the C language every time a macro is defined. At CWI we did write context-free grammars for C given a set of known macro definitions to extend the C language and that worked out fine, but that is not a general solution.